# Urban Airship Display In App Message On Specific ViewController

Tags: android, ios, swift, xamarin, urbanairship.com

I am using **Urban Airship** (UA) for Push Notification in my IOS and Android app. 
Currently, The app is set up to navigate through the below screens when the application launches:

[Splash screen] => [Loading Screen] => [Main Screen]

I am using the Urban Airship landing page feature to display an HTML content screen in the app when a notification is received.

**Problem:**

When a push notification is received and the application is not running, and the user taps on the notification; The application launches. UA tries to display the Landing Page associated with the push notification on the Loading Screen. When the loading screen is dismissed, so is the Push Notification Landing Page.  Instead, I need the notification to show on the Main Screen.

Is there any mechanism to tell UA which view controller to display the notification on?

Comment: Is this a Forms app? i.e are those screens a Forms' Page or a native Activity/UIViewController

Comment: No it is Xamarin Classic @SushiHangover

Comment: So each screen is a separate Activity or a UIViewController?

Comment: @SushiHangover separate view controller for iOS and separate activity for android

Comment: @wishmaster - Were you able to look for any alternative solution for this?